# How to check if all components are loaded in a .net core blazor app?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor

Let's say I want to know when all my component are loaded so that I can do X.

In my `MainLayout.razor` I'have for example this

```
@inject MyService;

@Body

bool AllComponentsAreLoaded { get; set; }

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    AllComponentsAreLoaded = false;
}

 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstrender)
 {
     AllComponentsAreLoaded = true;
     if (AllComponentsAreLoaded)
     {
         // Nice I can start X
     }
 }
```

This code will work but my problem is that there are components in `@Body` that aren't loaded.
The `OnAfterRenderAsync` will fire but it will do so before all components are done rendering.

How can I know that all components are done rendering?

Comment: In short, the answer is you can create a custom state provider that each component can use to let you know if all of the components have completed loading... I don't remember the exact implementation as it's on my work computer but I will try to post it tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

To do this, you can use a 'NotifierService' that you inject into the startup that each component can call (example in the below link).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components?view=aspnetcore-3.1

For example, each component would send a notification to this service, that can let it know if it was loaded or not. The main 'Body' would then be notified when it was completed (you'd have to implement your own logic here).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is differently some thing that could fix my problem.